# Logistic Regression test accuracy vs deployment

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, accuracy, confusion-matrix

I am working on a problem where I make some weekly predictions. I gathered the data myself and did some pre-processing steps and I end up with 6 features. I split the dataset 60-20-20 in train, holdout, test sets and I train a Logistic Regression model. I get very good holdout and test accuracy (>95%) with only a few FP, FN. However, when making predictions for new data in the end the results are nowhere near there. I make predictions weekly and past 2 weeks I have an accuracy of around 60%. How is this explained? I believe is important to note that 1 of my features has a 0.25 correlation with the target variable while the rest have 0.90. Is this what is causing the misleading high test accuracy? Thanks

Comment: There are likely „new“ observations in the predicted cases which are not well understood by the model: The model does not generalize well. Try to gather more data and retrain.

Comment: Do you perform the same pre-processing on the "new data"?

Comment: @Peter Probably but i think there is something fundamentally not working. For example, I have made predictions for 3 weeks so far (50 instances each) and got 60%, 60% and 25% correct. However, if I repeat my process and incorporate these 3 'new' weeks' data in my dataset, they naturally end up in the test set and then I still get 95% test accuracy.

rickhg12hs yes I follow the exact same pre-processing steps

Comment: Maybe there is some time trend not captured by your model. However, based on the information in your question it is impossible to tell what might be the problem

Comment: If you include the new data in the training set, does the test accuracy noticeably decrease?